# R Bioconductor: topGO Not Installing

Tags: linux, r, ubuntu, bioconductor

I've just finished downloading R and RStudios for use with Ubuntu 14.04. I have version R 3.0.2. I'm trying to install Bioconductor package topGO using RStudio. I used the code source(:http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R") and got the message: "Bioconductor version 2.13 ....a newer version of Bioconductor is available after installing newer version of R"

So I removed R from my computer and re-installed it. I think I have the newest version R version 3.0.2. I also ran biocLite("BiocUpgrade") on this new downmload of R and got the error message:

```
BioC_mirror: http://bioconductor.org
Using Bioconductor version 2.13 (BiocInstaller 1.12.1), R
  version 3.0.2.
Warning messages:
1: Bioconductor version 2.13 is the latest available for R
  version 3.0.0 
2: installed directory not writable, cannot update packages
  'boot', 'class', 'cluster', 'codetools', 'foreign',
  'KernSmooth', 'lattice', 'Matrix', 'mgcv', 'nlme', 'nnet',
  'rpart', 'spatial', 'survival'
```

I have no clue what this means so I just tried to download topGO using biocLite("topGO"). It starts to download but then stops and gives the error message:

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'GO.db', details:
  call: match.arg(synchronous, c("off", "normal", "full"))
  error: 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/sprout/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/GO.db’
ERROR: dependency ‘GO.db’ is not available for package ‘topGO’
* removing ‘/home/sprout/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/topGO’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpqFXYZT/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages(pkgs = pkgs, lib = lib, repos = repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘GO.db’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages(pkgs = pkgs, lib = lib, repos = repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘topGO’ had non-zero exit status
3: installed directory not writable, cannot update packages 'boot', 'class', 'cluster', 'codetools', 'foreign', 'KernSmooth',
  'lattice', 'Matrix', 'mgcv', 'nlme', 'nnet', 'rpart', 'spatial', 'survival'
```

Any thoughts? Thank you for the help!

Comment: I hate doing this, what do I type into the terminal to get this latest package of R? I'm trying  deb https://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu vivid/ but it says the command "deb" doesn't exist

Comment: If you have ubuntu 14.04 I suggest that you edit the file /etc/apt/sources.list and add the line `deb https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/` at the end, provided that you can read/write the file.

Comment: Once this is done, you can proceed with `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install r-base` and `sudo apt-get install r-base-dev`.

Comment: One more ?, how do you write in the sources.list file through the terminal? I've never done this before. I found the sources.list file, but can't write in it.

Comment: Probably a minimal editor such as gedit is installed. Try using `sudo gedit  /etc/apt/sources.list` . If you are allowed to read and write the file, this should be easy because this is a standard editor, comparable to Windows' notepad. If you don't have the permission to modify the file, let me know and we'll try to find another solution.

Comment: Could we discuss this in a chat? I don't have enough rep to do that. I did add the last line in the source.list file and ran the commands again. It looked like it did everything, but I checked the RStudio version and I still have 3.0.2

Comment: If the latest version of R doesn't show up in RStudio, then it is almost certainly not installed. Unlike Windows, where you can easily keep older versions of R, you typically have only one version of R in linux. Did you set the last part in the line to be added in the sources.list file to `trusty/`  as I described above? The attempt that you mentioned in the beginning, with `vivid/` at the end, is not suitable for ubuntu14.04.

Comment: I did, when I go to update my packages in the source.list using sudo apt-get update, I get the error message: W: GPG error: http://cran.stat.ucla.edu trusty/ Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available:

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a recent version of R on your computer. Several packages require a more recent version. I suggest that you follow the instructions at https://cran.r-project.org/ on how to install the latest version of R (which is currently v3.2.1) and try again.

Answer (score 0):

problem:**installed directory not writable, cannot update packages 'boot', 'class', 'cluster', 'codetools', 'foreign', 'KernSmooth',
  'lattice', 'Matrix', 'mgcv', 'nlme', 'nnet', 'rpart', 'spatial', 'survival'**

solution:Run R as a root user IN TERMINAL

1,sudo R
2,biocLite("BiocUpgrade") 
3,Update option:(type) a